# Deny access to records through querystring

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How do I prevent access to records that a user shouldn't have access to? For example:

User John123 can bring up a list of his data on the page site.com/Clients, and then can go to a details page, let's say ~/Clients?id=28

Another user Harry78 doesn't have access to those records, yet he can still see the above record by changing the URL to ~/Clients?id=28 .

How do I prevent this unauthorised access?  This is particularly important in the case of a page ~/EditClients where Harry78 should not be able to edit John123's records.

Comment: More info please. How are the users logging in? How do you capture their identity?

Comment: Using Identity, and stores them in AspNetUsers table. The only way I can see to do it is check the owner of that record against the logged in user and act accordingly. I was hoping that there maybe a shortcut to this.